# Best way to save sanitize html in angular

Tags: angular

I need to store a portion of html code in my database but in turn show it as a preview but in a safe way

I'm showing the preview like:

```
  <div class="preview" [innerHTML]="card | sanitize">
```

my sanitize pipe is basically doing this:

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text);
```

my question is, should I save the card text directly or should I apply:

```
this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, card);
```

the problem is that when I apply senitize and try to show it again it loses all the properties of the css.

or could you recommend a best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR: It's safe to use innerHTML.**

No need to sanitize manually with innerHTML, Angular automatically sanitizes it for you when there's an unsafe value. Check out Angular [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/security) for more details.

Quote from there:

> For the HTML to be interpreted, bind it to an HTML property such as
> innerHTML. But binding a value that an attacker might control into
> innerHTML normally causes an XSS vulnerability. For example, code
> contained in a  tag is executed:
>
> ```
> export class InnerHtmlBindingComponent {
>   // For example, a user/attacker-controlled value from a URL.
>   htmlSnippet = 'Template <script>alert("0wned")</script> <b>Syntax</b>';
> }
> ```
>
> Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it,
> which removes the  tag but keeps safe content such as the 
> element.